Using particle swarm optimization algorithm to find the optimal solution of MCMA blind equalization algorithm
I used the PSO algorithm to find the optimal solution for MCMA in this algorithm, and the generated constellation diagram showed that the modulus could be recovered, but the error rate was high. I found that the phase of the output signal has deviated by π n/2. For example, after the signal in the first quadrant is balanced, it changes to the fourth or second quadrant. Through analyzing the code, I found that the initial particle position may be random, which caused the generated filter to have a significant impact on the input signal, resulting in confusion. How can I modify the initialization of this particle position to correctly restore the original signal?
clc;
clear all;

L = 3000;
SNR = 25;
h = 0.059 + 0.051j;
h = h / norm(h);
Nf = 21;

M = 4;
sa = round(rand(L, 1) * (M - 1));
sn = qammod(sa', M);

rn = filter(h, 1, sn);
xn = awgn(rn, SNR, 'measured');

Ri = mean(imag(sn).^4) / mean(imag(sn).^2);
Rr = mean(real(sn).^4) / mean(real(sn).^2);
Ri = Ri / sqrt(Ri^2 + Rr^2);
Rr = Rr / sqrt(Ri^2 + Rr^2);

%% PSO Parameters
num_particles = 35;
max_iter = 300;
dim = 2 * Nf; % Variables to optimize (real and imaginary parts of W_mcma)
ub = 2; % Upper bound of position
lb = -2; % Lower bound of position
v_max = 0.1 * (ub - lb); % Upper bound of velocity
v_min = -v_max; % Lower bound of velocity
w = 0.7; % Inertia weight
c1 = 1.5; % Cognitive (personal) coefficient
c2 = 1.5; % Social (global) coefficient

% Initialize particles to be close to zero
particles = (ub - lb) * (rand(num_particles, dim) - 0.5);
velocities = zeros(num_particles, dim);
personal_best = particles;
global_best = particles(1, :);

% Initialize personal best values and global best value
personal_best_values = inf(num_particles, 1);
global_best_value = inf;

% Initialize fitness values array
global_best_values = zeros(1, max_iter);

% PSO Main Loop
for iter = 1:max_iter
    for i = 1:num_particles
        % Extract real and imaginary parts of W_mcma
        W_pso_real = particles(i, 1:Nf);
        W_pso_imag = particles(i, Nf+1:end);
        W_pso = W_pso_real + 1i * W_pso_imag;

        % Calculate fitness function (sum of squared errors at each time step)
        X_pso = zeros(Nf, L-Nf);
        Y_pso = zeros(1, L-Nf);
        Jr = zeros(1, L-Nf);
        Ji = zeros(1, L-Nf);

        for ik = 1:L-Nf
            X_pso(:, ik) = fliplr(xn(ik:ik+Nf-1));
            Y_pso(ik) = W_pso * X_pso(:, ik);
            Yr_pso = real(Y_pso(ik));
            Yi_pso = imag(Y_pso(ik));
            Jr(ik) = (Yr_pso^2 - Rr)^2;
            Ji(ik) = (Yi_pso^2 - Ri)^2;
        end
        Jr_mean = 1/4*mean(Jr);
        Ji_mean = 1/4*mean(Ji);
        J = Jr_mean + Ji_mean;
        fitness = mean(J);
        
        % Update personal best
        if fitness < personal_best_values(i)
            personal_best_values(i) = fitness;
            personal_best(i, :) = particles(i, :);
        end

        % Update global best
        if fitness < global_best_value
            global_best_value = fitness;
            global_best = particles(i, :);
        end
    end

    % Save the current iteration's global best fitness value
    global_best_values(iter) = global_best_value;

    % Update velocities and particle positions
    for i = 1:num_particles
        r1 = rand(1, dim);
        r2 = rand(1, dim);
        velocities(i, :) = w * velocities(i, :) + ...
            c1 * r1 .* (personal_best(i, :) - particles(i, :)) + ...
            c2 * r2 .* (global_best - particles(i, :));
        
        % Apply velocity bounds
        velocities(i, velocities(i, :) > v_max) = v_max;
        velocities(i, velocities(i, :) < v_min) = v_min;
        
        particles(i, :) = particles(i, :) + velocities(i, :);
        
        % Apply position bounds
        particles(i, particles(i, :) > ub) = ub;
        particles(i, particles(i, :) < lb) = lb;
    end

    % Display iteration number and global best fitness value
    disp(['Iteration ' num2str(iter) ' - Global Best Fitness Value: ' num2str(global_best_value)]);
end

% Extract the optimal W_mcma
W_real = global_best(1:Nf);
W_imag = global_best(Nf+1:end);
W_mcma = W_real + 1i * W_imag;

% Evaluate using the optimal W_mcma
X_mcma = zeros(Nf, L-Nf);
Y_mcma = zeros(1, L-Nf);
E_mcma = zeros(1, L-Nf);

for ik = 1:L-Nf
    X_mcma(:, ik) = fliplr(xn(ik:ik+Nf-1));
    Y_mcma(ik) = W_mcma * X_mcma(:, ik);
    Yr = real(Y_mcma(ik));
    Yi = imag(Y_mcma(ik));        
    Er_mcma = Yr * (Yr^2 - Rr);
    Ei_mcma = Yi * (Yi^2 - Ri);
    E_mcma(ik) = Er_mcma + 1i * Ei_mcma;
end

demod_Y_mcma_pso = qamdemod(Y_mcma, M);
sn1_delayed = sn(1:L-Nf); % Delayed by 10 symbols
demod_sn1_delayed = qamdemod(sn1_delayed, M);

num_err_mcma_pso = sum(demod_sn1_delayed ~= demod_Y_mcma_pso);
ser_mcma_pso = num_err_mcma_pso / length(demod_Y_mcma_pso);

disp(['SER: ' num2str(ser_mcma_pso)]);

% Plot constellations of the original signal, received signal, and equalized signal
figure;

subplot(2, 2, 1);
plot(sn, '*');
xlabel('Real Part');
ylabel('Imaginary Part');
xlim([-2, 2])
ylim([-2, 2])
title('Original Signal');
grid on;

subplot(2, 2, 2);
plot(xn, 'o');
xlabel('Real Part');
ylabel('Imaginary Part');
xlim([-4, 4])
ylim([-4, 4])
title('Received Signal');
grid on;

subplot(2, 2, 3);
plot(Y_mcma, 'o');
xlabel('Real Part');
ylabel('Imaginary Part');
title('Equalized Signal using PSO');
xlim([-2, 2])
ylim([-2, 2])
grid on;

subplot(2, 2, 4);
plot(1:L-Nf, abs(E_mcma));
xlabel('Iteration');
ylabel('Error Magnitude');
title('MCMA Algorithm Error Curve');
grid on;

figure;
plot(1:max_iter, global_best_values);
xlabel('Iteration');
ylabel('Fitness Value');
title('PSO Fitness Curve');
grid on;


This is the error rate after code simulation, and it can be seen that the error rate is very high

